# axis2: how to ignore HTTP response status code?

Tags: java, web-services, http, apache-axis

I have to connect with WebService that in case of error return the same SOAP envelope as in case of normal operation, but sets HTTP status to "500 Internal Server Error". Then I got exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The MessageContext does not have an associated SOAPFault.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:455)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

When I change (on my emulator) HTTP status to `200 OK` then all works fine. My `InFlow` and `InFaultFlow` are the same.

How can I set axis2 to ignore HTTP status or use normal `InFlow` for responses with HTTP status 5xx?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551705/axis2-how-to-ignore-http-response-status-code !!

Comment: Yes, it was duplicated. I deleted one copy of my question.